# Qml flicker on animation in frameless QQuickView (QtQuick2)

Tags: c++, qml, flicker, qquickview

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQuickView *view= new QQuickView;
    view->setFlags(Qt::Tool|Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint|Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    view->setColor(Qt::transparent);
    view->show();
    view->setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

qmlfile:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    color: "#80808080"

    Rectangle {
        width: 10
        height: 10
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        RotationAnimation on rotation {
            duration : 15000
            easing.type: Easing.Linear
            loops: Animation.Infinite
            from: 0
            to: 360
        }
    }
}
```

The transparent background [flickers](https://youtu.be/6fg-KJq9caU), but only with an animation. The example is pretty basic, so whats the problem?

Comment: Well, it ain't the QML code, maybe a problem with platform support? Does it flicker if you don't set those extra view flags?

Comment: Nope. Without FramelessWindowHint everthing is fine.

Comment: Well, it looks like a bug, you should post a bug report. Just don't hold your breath for a quick resolution :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
Set the environment variable to QSG_RENDER_LOOP=basic

Long answer:
I dont know the exact internals. The Qmlscene is rendered by multiple threads when QSG_RENDER_LOOP=threaded is set. But some drivers fail in rendering smooth animations. Hence for untested systems (x11,mesa) initially QSG_RENDER_LOOP was set to basic. Since 5.5 threaded is the default.

Answer (score 0):

Try "view->setFlags(Qt::SplashScreen)"
Maybe solve this issue, but the window can't be resized and moved. It doesn't make sense, but it is.